# Promiscuous mode network traffic stat util?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-monitoring

I want to get a stat of packets/bytes from/to each IP in the network.

Wireshark is too heavy for me, and tcpdump has no stat function.

vnstat seems not aware of IP address at all.

Any choice?

Answer (score 1):

[ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) is always a good choice.

`tethereal` is the tty version of ethereal, its light(er) or resources, same functions and engine.

[image]

Comment: Ethereal is now [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/news/20060607.html), and also tshark for tethereal.